# C++ loop -get error llbd on xcode 6.4

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I need help on a loop that I am trying to build. I have to write this for loop to print out the values (1,2,4,8,16,32,64) by increasing the value of  the counting variable by a factor of two in each loop cycle. Sorry for the wording I am just a noob trying to learn C++ .

```
  #include <iostream>
  int main()
  {
    int i;
     for (i = 0; i < 64;)
  {
    std::cout<< i << std:: endl;
    i = i * 2;
  }
    return 0;
  }
```

And all I get as out is (llbd)

I looked up a few questions here and there was a mention of updating the scheme to gbd- this version of xcode apparently does not have the option to change schemes?

The other option was to backtrace and this is what I got...

```
  (lldb) bt
  * thread #1: tid = 0x61405, 0x0000000100000d5f scrap2`main + 15 at  main.cpp:16,  queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100000d5f scrap2`main + 15 at main.cpp:16
  frame #1: 0x00007fff8f3b35c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
  frame #2: 0x00007fff8f3b35c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
  (lldb)
```

I have no idea what this means. It's a little too advance for me at the moment. Any bit of knowledge will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop seems to be a never ending loop because the value of `i` is always `0`. It will never show `64` either because you have `<` less than instead of less than or equal to `<=`.

**Solution**:

```
Initialize i with a value of 1 and change the < to <=
```

Comment: Oh yes of course! I can't believe that I didn't catch that! So I chanced the variable from i to x...which saved some trouble.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you got the lldb, but for the algorithm I have some suggestions. The problem of your algorithm is that the value of i will remain 0, no matter how many times you double it. My solution is to set i as the exponent.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        cout<<val<<endl;
        val *= 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you edit it to add an explanation of how it works and why it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Blackwood

Comment: I made some changes at to adding the i++ and changing the placement of the multiplication symbol which helped. Thank you!